# YUI 3 IO Utility - form submission with file upload removes HTML from responseText

Tags: javascript, yui

I am using the YUI3 IO Utility to submit a form with a file. The response from the server contains HTML but it is stripped when accessed on the request object.

```
var form = Y.one('form');
Y.io(form.get('action'), {
    method: form.get('method'),
    form: {
        id: form,
        upload: true
    },
    on: {
        complete: function(id, request) {
            // The server returns a response like <div>response</div>
            console.log(request.responseText); 
            // All HTML is stripped so it just prints 'response' to the console
        }
    }
});
```

Is this considered the default behaviour? I almost can't believe that it is not possible to get the full response content ...
The server also sets the content-type header properly to "text/html".

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had a look at the YUI3 source code. The few lines that are responsible for the request object in https://raw.github.com/yui/yui3/master/src/io/js/io-upload-iframe.js are:

```
_uploadComplete: function(o, c) {
    var io = this,
        d = Y.one('#io_iframe' + o.id).get('contentWindow.document'),
        b = d.one('body'),
        p;

    if (c.timeout) {
        io._clearUploadTimeout(o.id);
    }

    try {
        if (b) {
            // When a response Content-Type of "text/plain" is used, Firefox and     Safari
            // will wrap the response string with <pre></pre>.
            p = b.one('pre:first-child');
            o.c.responseText = p ? p.get('text') : b.get('text');
            Y.log('The responseText value for transaction ' + o.id + ' is: ' +     o.c.responseText + '.', 'info', 'io');
        }
        else {
            o.c.responseXML = d._node;
            Y.log('The response for transaction ' + o.id + ' is an XML     document.', 'info', 'io');
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        o.e = "upload failure";
    }

    io.complete(o, c);
    io.end(o, c);
    // The transaction is complete, so call _dFrame to remove
    // the event listener bound to the iframe transport, and then
    // destroy the iframe.
    w.setTimeout( function() { _dFrame(o.id); }, 0);
},
```

So as soon as the response contains a "body" node it returns the body content as "text".

```
o.c.responseText = p ? p.get('text') : b.get('text');
```

IMHO there is no chance to get the innerHTML if there is a body node. I decided to create a customized IO Upload Iframe module that adds an additional property called "responseHTML" with the innerHTML of the body node.

You can get the source from Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/WadQgNP2

Answer (score 0):

http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/io/#the-response-object

The `responseXML` property might contain what you're looking for. If that doesn't help you try changing `console.log(request.responseText);` to `console.log(request);` and go through it's properties in your debugger (e.g. Firebug) to find the one containing the data you require.

Keep in mind that in general all properties called `...Text` will only return the text contents of something, completely stripped of XML code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it does not even contain the reponseXML property. I finally created a modified IO Upload Iframe module that returns the innerHTML as as an additional property (responseHTML). I will add it as an answer to my question.